# How to use conditional statement within onTap

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a problem regarding if statement in dart, I want the user to tap the city to go to a new screen. this code work perfectly fine

```
class citySec extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget getListView(BuildContext context) {
    var listView = ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "choose ur city:",
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.location_city),
          title: Text("Toronto ", textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),

          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => TorontoUniversitySection(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
    return listView;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: getListView(context));
  }
}
```

Since I have a long list of cities and the previous code will make my code very long so I had to change my code. However, I faced some errors with if statements, here is what I did so far.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rate/screens/firstScreen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'Rate',
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("jgfnjfnj ", textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
      ),
      body: ListDisplay(),
    ),
  ));
}
class ListDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> litems = ["Toronto","NewYork","London","Riyadh","Dubai","Istanbul"];

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Please Choose your city: ", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,),
      ),

    body: new ListView.builder
    (
    itemCount: litems.length,

    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {

    return new ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.location_city),
      title: Text(litems[index], textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),

      onTap: () {
// begin of all IF statements

        if (litems.contains("Totonto")){
          Navigator.push(
            ctxt,
            MaterialPageRoute(

              builder: (ctxt) => TorontoUniversitySection()
            ),
          );

        }
if (litems.contains("London")){
          Navigator.push(
            ctxt,
            MaterialPageRoute(

              builder: (ctxt) => LondonUniversitySection()
            ),
          );

        }

// end of all If statements

      },
    );

    }
    )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What are your errors ?

Comment: so when i press toronto it goes to Toronto but when i have another item in the list and i press any item it goes to last execute the last item that i added

Comment: for example, when I press Toronto it will take me to  LondonUniversitySection()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example, when I press Toronto it will take me to LondonUniversitySection()

That is because in your if statements, you check *whether your list contains Toronto/London* and not if currently pressed one is Toronto/London. Changing `litems.contains("x")` to `litems[index] == "x"` will do the trick. Here's edited fragment:

```
    return new ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.location_city),
      title: Text(litems[index], textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
      onTap: () {
        if (litems[index] == "Toronto") {
          Navigator.push(
            ctxt,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => TorontoUniversitySection()),
          );
        } else if (litems[index] == "London") {
          Navigator.push(
            ctxt,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => LondonUniversitySection()));
        }
      },
    );
```

Also, I recommend using a `switch` or `else-if` for that, not a bunch of ifs.

Comment: Also consider using constants for city labels. It's too easy to make a typo and write "Totonto" and a typo will result in application that is not working and no errors thrown.

Comment: Hmm I was wondering why it's not working but that makes a lot sense now, Thanks I will practice more

Answer (score 0):

Try `onTap: litems.contains("Totonto")?
 Navigator.push( ctxt, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (ctxt) => TorontoUniversitySection() ), )
: null`

Comment: still same result

Comment: Sorry i am not getting the error or bug that u are facing , but i think u need to use `index` positions of list to determine the specific items in the list and based on that provide the conditions

Comment: so should I add it inside onTap() or instead of onTap(), sorry I'm new to flutter

Comment: If your TorontoUniversitySection and LondonUniversitySection Page contains the same UI to display data , i would suggest you to create a common Page for all listitems and just pass the listItem as a variable and access the data specific to their index position on Static page

Comment: I will consider your advice, both pages contain long listview

Answer (score 0):

```
class _RegisterBodyState extends State<RegisterBody> {
  FocusNode myFocusNode = new FocusNode();
  FocusNode myFocusNode2 = new FocusNode();
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
    myFocusNode2 = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    myFocusNode.dispose();
    myFocusNode2.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  Color color;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Register",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                fontSize: 70.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            Form(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      color = Colors.red;
                    });
                  },
                  autofocus: true,
                  focusNode: myFocusNode,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.supervised_user_circle,
                      size: 40.0,
                    ),
                    labelText: "User Name",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color:
                            myFocusNode.hasFocus ?color : Colors.yellow),
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  focusNode: myFocusNode2,
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      color = Colors.black;
                    });
                  },
                  autofocus: false,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.supervised_user_circle,
                      size: 40.0,
                    ),
                    labelText: "User Name",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: myFocusNode2.hasFocus ? color : Colors.teal,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```